# Hooks doesn't work in CodeIgniter 2.X

Tags: codeigniter-2

I've enable hooks in config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

here is the hook.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hooks
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you define "hooks" to extend CI without hacking the core
| files.  Please see the user guide for info:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
|
*/

$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Authorization',
    'function' => 'authorize',
    'filename' => 'authorization.php',
    'file_path' => 'hooks'
);

/* End of file hooks.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/hooks.php */
```

and here is the authorization.php file under application/hooks/

```
<?php 


    class Authorization {

        private $ci;

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->ci = get_instance();
        }

        function authorize()
        {
            echo 'This should be outputed';
        }

    }

?>
```

but it doesn't work. doesn't anybody know why?

Comment: Have you find some solution to this? I'm having the same issue but specifically doesn't work when a POST form is submitted, but for a GET request made by the browser works fine.

Comment: I could finally solve the problem. When I try to use a hook with `post_system` it doesn't work for a POST form submission because I do a redirect within a controller and invoke another controller, so only for the last controller the hook was invoked.

I solved the problem using the hook point `post_controller_constructor`, so when a request was handle by a controller and this redirect the request to another controller the hook was invoked in both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Codigniter 2.1 and it works.. but my hook file is called 'MainLoader' and starts like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MainLoader {

  public function mainLoader()
  {

      $CI =& get_instance();

      echo 'This should be outputed';

      //Whatever you want to do here

  }
```

I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the [] next to the array variable.
In your code it written :

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Authorization',
    'function' => 'authorize',
    'filename' => 'authorization.php',
    'file_path' => 'hooks'
);
```

I think it should be like this :

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => 'Authorization',
    'function' => 'authorize',
    'filename' => 'authorization.php',
    'file_path' => 'hooks'
);
```

note the **[]** next to the **$hook['post_controller_constructor']** variable.

Hope this help. Thank you..